# Display: Table and Table-Cell

Tags: html, css

I want to make a following layout:

```
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***____________________________________][__][____]
```

The elements without stars are with fixed width, with stars should fill all remaining space.

And here is the markup I came up with:

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="label">text</div><input type="text" class="valueField"/>
 <div class="label">text</div><input type="text" class="valueField"/>
 <div class="label">text</div><input type="text" class="valueField"/><div class="label">text</div><input type="text" class="valueField" id="fixed_valueField"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper { display:table; width:100%; }
.wrapper > * { display:table-cell; width:auto; }
.label { width:5%; }
#fixed_valueField { width:15%; }
```

but on the third line my input element is not filling all available space:

```
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***______________________________________________]
[___][_***________________][__][____]
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `[___]` is yout `label` and `[_***______________________________________________]` your `input`?

Comment: yes. and the last element also input.

Answer (score 0):

Add the remaining percents to your CSS and an important to your ID to override:

```
.valueField { width: 80%; }
#fixed_valueField { width: 15% !important; }
```

That should work

Comment: the #fixed_valueField remains about half the space even if I put 100%. When I put smaller value like 20% it shrinks to 20%, but it doesn't grow after about half the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Smarter way to achieve your target would be to use `<label>` tags instead of `div` tag as it gives a better flow to form elements!

**DEMO**
 [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/x4vrY/2/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="valueField"/></label> <br >
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="valueField"/></label> <br >
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="valueField"/></label> <br >
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="valueField"/></label> <br >
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="valueField"/></label> <br >
      <label for="">text<input type="text" class="span6"/><input type="text" class="span2"/><input type="text" class="span2"/></label> <br >
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 label { width:100%;}
input {width:80%;margin-left:2%;border:1px solid #CCC}
.span6{width:45%} /*css for last row inputs*/
.span2{width:15%} /*css for last row inputs*/
```

Comment: updated fiddle link considering your last row input!

Comment: That works fine actually, but not exactly what I had in mind. I wanted to use auto with instead of manually calculating because for instance if I change padding or add thicker border to elements then the whole layout will scramble.